# asp .net view state option in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate

I have an asp .net application. I had the responsibility to deploy this code in our development servers. I deployed the code using the package that was provided and the installation was successful. But when I tried to lauch the login page, I am getting server error with the following message

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

If I set enableviewstate and enableviewstatemac = false then I am able to run the code and see all the pages. I know about view state but dont have in depth knowledge on this area. Can someone tell me how I can enable view state and still have my application run without compromising any security related issues? I dont have in depth knowledge on using the validation key in conjunction with view state.

Also this application is currently in production and I was responsible to maintain from now on. So I hope the package given to me should work perfectly as it works in production without removing the view state in web.config. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of viewstate storage are you using? Is it saved in sql, on the client, in the session?

Comment: @linkerro Its not in SQL. Its the normal view state you would use. It will be stored as a hidden variable in the client. Not sure if that is what the default viewstatw would do. But damn sure that the default viewstate is only used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Web Farm this is possible, you should share the same validationKey in all servers (instead of random generated per server). Check this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rich_crane/archive/2004/05/12/130693.aspx

You may write something like:

```
<machineKey  
validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7
               AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"           
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

Values depends on the algorithm you selected. You can use a random string or generate a custom one using `System.Security.*` classes. For more details check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) on MSDN, it explain all these stuffs in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Consider my development server case. Its just that one server. Thats it. So do you advice me to set a validation key attribute in web.config? Can you suggest me a sample then? Normally this validation key is something that server generates or we set it manually in web.config file? Do we give any value for the key or it is generated using a program?

Comment: I added an example and another link the answer. Normally it's auto-generated by the server and you do not need to specify a fixed one in the web.config (if you're not using a farm). You may check your host, maybe it's using a farm to distribute the load.